# how can I get only last modified date

Tags: shell, command

how can I get ONLY the filename and its last modified date of the files contained into a folder (even subfolders)

I want this kind of result:

```
path/filename  lastmodified_date
```

or

```
filename lastmodified_date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find /p/a/t/h -type f -printf '%p %t\n'
```

Will show you the name and mtime of every file below `/p/a/t/h`.  To get an epoch time instead of the long form, use:

```
find /p/a/t/h -type f -printf '%p %T@\n'
```

Check the documentation for `find` for instructions on how to change the format of the timestamp.

Comment: can I manipulate format of date? for example, I don't want hh:mm.ss but only hh:mm

Comment: Yes.  RTFM.  Not all `find` support printf, but those that do provide format strings to manipulate the output.  If your `find` does not provide -printf, then use `-exec` to invoke `stat` to print an epoch time and filter the output with perl to produce the format you desire.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get list files using glob() or scandir() after, you need to get last modified dates using filemtime().

Try this code

```
$files = scandir('./'); // Get list files current dir
$times = array_map('filemtime', $files); // Get last modified date each file
$result = array_combine($files, $times); // Set file names as array index and times as value
```

Now we have array with filenames and last modified date its. You can get data by using  `foreach($result as $filename => $date)` $data will have unix-time date.

Comment: on each file found with scandir() I must invoke filemtime(), right?

Comment: I don't want only the last modified file, I want each filename and it mtime.